# Python loop to get the first n value's average and variance for panel data

Tags: python, loops

This is my first question. I am hoping to get an idea of an efficient python loop code to achieve something different from moving average and moving variance; but the average and variance from the first value to the (n-1)<sup>th</sup>, my data structure is the follows:

First column is id, there are many repeated ids, one id has multiple values with a sequence (second column, 1,2,...,n) and value (third column). Each id may have different maximum sequence (n).

What I want to achieve, is to have two more columns, one is average, one is variance. For each id, I want to calculate the average value of the first n-1's "values" (first n in terms of sequence). And repeat that for variance.

Anyone to help?

I don't know how to post the data here, if anyone could tell me it will be great. Copy/paste from excel does not work.

Comment: What did you tried so far? For the data, you can, in any case, post a screenshot of your excel sheet.

Comment: have you looked into pandas at all? i feel like it could help you here.

Comment: @acushner, I am yet to look into pandas. I used to use stata and R, recently getting into python. any suggestions are welcome! I know pandas have the rolling mean function but that is different from what I want to achieve.

Comment: @RubenBermudez, I use R mostly and have R code for it. Yet to get the python. thank you!